# How to force Firefox to download file (custom extension, non-text file) versus display it?

Tags: react-native, api, file, firefox, download

I fear this might be a bug with firefox, as this seems to work fine on any other browser I've used.  If it is not a bug, what steps need to happen to force a download (versus a display in browser) of a file that can't be displayed in the browser.

Created a react site with a fastapi backend, through the api I am able to attain the url for a file to download.

A standard Anchor element is created for the download, when the user presses a button:

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
```

but I get a matrix screen of characters rather than a download (only on firefox).  I have another file on the same page that is text-based and through the same process get a "save file box" pop-up from firefox.

I've tried, surrounding the above code with

```
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

and

```
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

as I read that at one time firefox required that.

I've tried using the settings in firefox to force a download e.g. "Save File", but the extension is not listed and I changed all the extensions and the selection for "other files" to "ask whether to open or save files"

[image]
[image]

On the Anchor Element table of browser compatibility
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a
there is an * for firefox that says "see implementation notes", yet the only notes I see referring to firefox are

```
If the Content-Disposition header has different information from the download attribute, resulting behavior may differ:

    If the header specifies a filename, it takes priority over a filename specified in the download attribute.
    If the header specifies a disposition of inline, Chrome and Firefox prioritize the attribute and treat it as a download. Old Firefox versions (before 82) prioritize the header and will display the content inline.
```

Which I am unsure how to use that information, I have the latest firefox version and the above code works fine on Chrome and other browsers.  There doesn't seem to be much information about "specifying a disposition of inline", at least for react.

I can also take the link directly from the api and put it in the different browsers with the same effect (outside of the react/web front end).  The only one that tries to open the file is firefox, the rest download it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> There doesn't seem to be much information about "specifying a disposition of inline", at least for react.

The Content-Disposition header is an HTTP header and needs to be set on the HTTP response given **by the server**.

React has nothing to do with it as it runs on the client.

(And you want to set the disposition to `attachment`, not `inline`, since the `download` attribute isn't working).

---

> but I get a matrix screen of characters rather than a download (only on firefox).

This suggests that:

- The `download` attribute isn't working *anywhere* (likely because you are making a cross-origin request so the attribute isn't supported).
- The `content-type` of whatever the URL points to is either:

  - Wrong
  - Just not recognised by Firefox

… and downloads in other browsers are triggered by them recognising the content-type correctly (i.e. not the `download` attribute).

---

The solution is going to involve changing the `Content-Type` (if it is wrong) and/or `Content-Disposition` (to specify that the resource is an `attachment` and so should be downloaded and not displayed inline) of the resource the URL points to.